# How to disable SSL certificate verification using Webflux Web Client Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, spring-webflux

I have been trying to call my post endpoint setting my ssl certificate verification turn off from postman and it work fine.

[image]

I just want the same thing (to turn off the ssl certificate verification) as i m doing using postman in the code below:

```java
WebClient webClient =  WebClient.create("abc.com.pk");
String endPoint = "auth/connect/token";
HashMap<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("client_id", "abc12345");
params.put("username", "tom");
params.put("password", "jerry");
params.put("grant_type", "password");

try {
    HashMap map = webClient.post().uri(
                    uriBuilder ->
                            uriBuilder
                                    .path(endPoint)
                                    .build())
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .body(Mono.just(new Gson().toJson(params)), String.class)
            .retrieve().bodyToMono(HashMap.class)
            .block();
   return new Gson().toJson(map);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return "fail";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an insecure `TrustManagerFactory` that trusts all X.509 certificates without any verification. This will allow `WebClient` to communicate with a URL having any https certificate (self-signed, expired, wrong host, untrusted root, revoked, etc).

Setup your `WebClient` like this:

```
SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder
        .forClient()
        .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
        .build();
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(t -> t.sslContext(sslContext));
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).build();
```